# Function type setting 'this' context, not working

Tags: typescript, vue.js

I have the following code in my Vue component:

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import { ElForm } from 'element-ui/types/form';

type Validator = (
  this: typeof PasswordReset,
  rule: any,
  value: any,
  callback: (error?: Error) => void
) => void;

const validatePass1: Validator = (rule, value, callback) => {
  if (value && this.form.passwordConfirm) {
    (this.$refs.form as ElForm).validateField('passwordConfirm', valid => {});
  }
};
// ...

const PasswordReset = Vue.extend({
  // ...
```

This is not working as documented. I get a type error in the `validatePass1` func:

```
'this' implicitly has type 'any' because it does not have a type annotation.
```

I don't understand why this isn't working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`validatePass1` needs to be defined with the `function` keyword instead of as an arrow function.  An arrow function ignores the `this` passed at the time of the call (which is what your type annotation is on) and always uses the `this` from where it was defined, which in this case is the global object (I think).

Comment: That could be true. But I can't figure out how to define a function and set its type at the same time.

Comment: `const validatePass1: Validator = function(rule, value, callback) { ... }` should work.

Comment: Oops, duh. Brain fart. Lemme try that.

Comment: Got it! I've been staring at TS failures too long. :)